# @media does not work

Tags: css, media

I'm having trouble with getting my media query to work on a homework assignment. I think I've done everything correct and I've spent over 2 hours trying to understand why it doesn't seem to make any changes when viewing from a mobile device. If any one has any ideas it would help a ton. attached is my head section of html and my css code that follows my standard css.

```
<head>
<title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="pacific.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="pacificprint.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
</head>

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
body { margin: 0 ;
        padding: 0 ;
        background-image: none }
#wrapper { width: auto ;
            min-width: 0 ;
            margin: 0 ;
            box-shadow: none }
h1 { margin: 0 }
nav { float: none ;
        width: auto ;
        padding: 0.5em }
nav li { display: inline-block }
nav a { padding: 1em }
main { padding: 1em ;
        margin-left: 0 ;
        font-size: 90% }
footer { margin: 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that half of your CSS rules don't end with a semicolon.

While the final CSS semicolon can indeed be omitted in a statement, **[at-rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule)** (like media queries) constitute a statement **themselves**:

[image]

> A statement is a building block that begins with any non-space characters and ends at the first closing brace or semi-colon (outside a string, non-escaped and not included into another `{}`, `()` or `[]` pair).

As such, only your **last** rule can have the semicolon omitted (the `footer`).

Having said that, adding semicolons to every line is good practice, and will not cause any problems, so it's something you should always aim for.

I've formatted the code and added semicolons to every line in the following (now working) example:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: none;
  }
  #wrapper {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  nav li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav a {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  main {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  footer {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="pacific.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="pacificprint.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
</head>
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the example as well.